# How to invoke function SOAP with oauth?

Tags: php, codeigniter, soap, oauth

I want to invoke a function with oauth use soap client. I have a consumer key then I generate timestamp, nonce, and signature..

When I run, I get error

> "Undefined property: SoapFault::$CreateWebUserResult"

This is my code :

```
function index(){
    $this->url = 'location?wsdl';
    $param = $this->expURL();
    $context = array('http' =>
        array(
            'header'  => 'Authorization: OAuth 
                oauth_nonce="'.$param['nonce'].'",
                oauth_timestamp="'.$param['timeStamp'].'",
                oauth_version="'.$param['version'].'",
                oauth_signature_method="'.$param['signatureMethod'].'",
                oauth_consumer_key="'.$param['consumerKey'].'",
                oauth_signature="'.$param['signature'].'"',
            'method' => 'GET'
        )
    );

    try{
        $client = new SoapClient($this->url,array(
        'stream_context'=>stream_context_create($context), "trace" => 1, "exceptions" => 0, "cache_wsdl" => 0));

        $input = array(
            "pUsername" => strval(''),
            "pPassword" => strval(''),
            "pEmail" => strval(''),
            "pIsApproved" => true
        );
        $result = json_decode($client->CreateWebUser($input)->CreateWebUserResult, true);
        print_r($client);

    }catch (SoapFault $e){
        var_dump($e);
    }
}
```

Web service in server use .net... So, I use stream context to pass oauth in header.. But it's not solve... Please help me....